# What is a thread-safe random number generator for perl?

Tags: windows, multithreading, perl, random, thread-safety

The core perl function rand() is not thread-safe, and I need random numbers in a threaded monte carlo simulation.

I'm having trouble finding any notes in CPAN on the various random-number generators there as to which (if any) are thread-safe, and every google search I do keeps getting cluttered with C/C++/python/anything but perl. Any suggestions?

Comment: In what sense is it not thread-safe? Do you mean that it can generate the same sequence of numbers in each thread? Then all you have to do is seed it (see `srand`) in the new thread/process after you create it.

Comment: As in it's marked as not thread-safe, and when I use it all my threads get piled on one core instead of properly distributed by the operating system :)

Comment: OK, now I don't know WHAT isn't working. I've made an incredibly bare-bones threading test, and with or without rand the load gets distributed properly. No idea if the results are garbage though, I haven't checked that. Clearly something harder to fix (ie my fault) is going on in my program.

Comment: There's no way that using it would cause your thread to go to one core.

Answer (score 2):

[Do not use built-in `rand` for Monte Carlo on Windows](http://blog.nu42.com/2010/09/be-vary-of-using-built-in-rng-for.html). At least, try:

```
my %r = map { rand() => undef } 1 .. 1_000_000;
print scalar keys %r, "\n";
```

If nothing has changed, it should print `32768` which is utterly unsuitable for any kind of serious work. And, even if it does print a larger number, you're better off sticking with a PRNG with known good qualities for simulation.

You can use [Math::Random::MT](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Math%3a%3aRandom%3a%3aMT).

You can instantiate a new `Math::Random::MT` object in each thread with its own array of seeds. [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister#Advantages) has good properties for simulation.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `/dev/urandom` on your system?

```
BEGIN {
    open URANDOM, '<', '/dev/urandom';
}

sub urand {  # drop in replacement for rand.
    my $expr = shift || 1;
    my $x;
    read URANDOM, $x, 4;
    return $expr * unpack("I", $x) / (2**32);
}
```

Comment: Looks like it's not available on windows systems (No such file or directory).

Answer (score -2):

rand is thread safe, and I think you got the wrong definition of what "thread safe" means, If its not "thread safe" It means the program/function is modifying its "shared" data structure that makes its execution in thread mode unsafe.

Check Rand function documentation, Notice it take EXPR as argument, in every thread you can provide a different EXPR.

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rand.html

Comment: I don't understand your point about providing a different EXPR in each thread. Perhaps you are thinking of providing a different EXPR to `srand`?

Comment: you can see that in the function example EXPR could be anything , In the example they have used integer 10. int(rand(10))

Comment: After that explanation, I understand even less.

Comment: Did you read the documentaion? What is confusing?                     If srand() is not called explicitly, it is called implicitly without a parameter at the first use of the rand operator.