# generate cryptographically-secure random number/string in perl

Tags: perl, perl-module, mod-perl

I need to select random characters from a set of characters say 0..9,a-z,A-z etc. For this I need to generate random integer number between 0-n ( n is the number of different characters) using Perl script. But Perl rand function is not cryptographically-secure. What is the best way to generate random number.

Right now I am using my own algorithm where I have chosen the character string randomly. Then I am generating a random number using rand. Using which I am selecting a decimal number among the random set of numbers.Then multiplying it with the random number. Whatever i am getting is the index of the characters chosen.

```
my @chars = ('a'..'d','#','N'..'Z','$','e'..'f','0'..'9');
my @random_numbers_list = ('1.0145','1.3464','1.8453','1.5145','1.9994');
my $random_string;
my $random_number;
my $chars_length = scalar @chars;
foreach (1 .. $length) {
            $random_number = (rand $chars_length)*$random_numbers_list[rand(5)];
            $random_number = ($random_number>$chars_length)?$random_number-$chars_length:$random_number;
            $random_string .= $chars[$random_number];
}
print $random_string;
```

I know i keep on increase the random_numbers_list size, it will be more and more secure. But still i am not sure that it is the best way to achieve this.

Please let me know the best approach to generate a cryptographically-secure random string/number.

Thanks

Comment: You should try saving everyone time by [**searching the web**](http://www.google.com/search?q=perl+cryptographic+random+number) before posting.

Comment: Related: [What is a thread-safe random number generator for perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15574374/what-is-a-thread-safe-random-number-generator-for-perl), which warns about using the `rand` built-in on Windows and recommends [Math::Random::MT](http://p3rl.org/Math::Random::MT).

Answer (score 6):

[`Math::Random::Secure`](http://search.cpan.org/~mkanat/Math-Random-Secure-0.06/lib/Math/Random/Secure.pm) is one solution (utilizes `/dev/urandom` on Linux).

[`Crypt::Random`](http://search.cpan.org/~vipul/Crypt-Random-1.25/lib/Crypt/Random.pm) is probably a better solution (utilizes `/dev/random`, and as such, may block).

Answer (score -4):

On the other hand, you have Perl modules at CPAN that gives you that funcionallity, like [String::Random](http://search.cpan.org/~steve/String-Random-0.22/lib/String/Random.pm)

Comment: I don't see anything about that being cryptographically secure - which is the primary concern of the OP.

Comment: I said it as an alternative; your answer is fine but mine looks for another way to solve the problem

Comment: But I don't think yours is a *valid* way to solve the problem. The OP *explicitly* asks for a cryptographically-secure RNG. Your solution does *not* meet that criteria. Therefore it is an invalid answer.

Comment: Yes. Read the documentation. It says *nothing* about cryptographic security. If it doesn't explicitly state that it is cryptographically secure, then it *isn't*.  Not sure what the discussion is right now.